# How to use EXPORT / IMPORT to Memory

Tags: memory, import, export, abap

I'm trying to export a value for an enhancement inside a BAPI call, that is executed in a background update task. But the value is not being read inside the enhancement, however if I do a local test the value is read correctly from memory.

Any ideas as to why this doesn't work?

This is my code:

Export program:

```
DATA: lv_id TYPE char30.

CONCATENATE 'ZTCODE' sy-uname
  INTO lv_id.

EXPORT ztcode FROM iv_tcode TO MEMORY ID lv_id.
```

Import program(inside enhancement):

```
DATA: lv_tcode  TYPE sy-tcode,
      lv_id     TYPE char30.

CONCATENATE 'ZTCODE' sy-uname
  INTO lv_id.

IMPORT ztcode TO lv_tcode FROM MEMORY ID lv_id.
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apparently you are trying to transfer data from a user session to a background/update session. This won't work using the ABAP memory. Check the documentation on the [ABAP Memory Organization](http://help.sap.com/abapdocu_750/en/abenmemory_organization.htm): An RFC call or an update module is run in a different user session which has a different ABAP Memory.

Comment: Thanks, that diagram explains it nicely.
One related question though, I haven't found proper documentation for it, do you know the benefits/differences of using the EXPORT with "TO DATABASE indx(st)" adition?

Comment: Have you checked the online help / syntax documentation on that statement?

Comment: Yes, but its not clear what the diff is. And sometimes it works if I use the "TO DATABASE" syntax, but not without it, that is why I asked...

Comment: If [this](http://help.sap.com/abapdocu_750/en/ABAPEXPORT_DATA_CLUSTER_MEDIUM.htm) doesn't make it clear, it will be difficult to explain it any better.: _the data cluster is written in to ABAP Memory_ vs. _the data cluster with the ID id is stored in the database table dbtab_

Comment: So, what was your final solution?